# How to define static Map for whole spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring

I'm a newbie with java spring mvc framework. Please tell me how to define static map variable for whole spring mvc application.
In my case, I have some catalog as :

- user status catalog: enable, disable;
- project status catalog as  started, working, done...

I want to set there catalogs as global constant in my application. But i don't know how.
Thank for any help!

Comment: This map should be your database, shouldn't it? You define a static Map the same way as you would in any other context. What's the problem?

Comment: If you want compile time defined list of status value you may consider enumeration.

Comment: "This map should be your database" is one way to solve problem but it litle bit complicated for database

Answer (score 1):

You can declare two lists (under the `util` namespace) and a map.

```
<!-- a list that holds the user status values -->
<util:list id="userStatus">
    <value>enable</value>
    <value>disable</value>
</util:list>

<!-- a list that holds the project status values -->
<util:list id="projectStatus">
    <value>started</value>
    <value>working</value>
    <value>done</value>
</util:list>

<util:map id="myMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="userStatuses"><ref bean="userStatus"/></entry>
    <entry key="projectStatuses"><ref bean="projectStatus"/></entry>
</util:map>
```

Note that the three of them are valid Spring beans with a (default) scope of `singleton`, which means a single instance of theirs will be shared across the application.